# Run liquibase change set in parallel

Tags: liquibase

We are using liquibase for database upgrade. Change set are executed sequentially on all database schemas. We fetch list of schemas and iterate it and execute change set on each schema. Running sequentially is taking a lot of time.
Our intent is to execute same set of change sets on all schemas in parallel. Does liquibase support this kind of functionality. If I have a list of db schemas, can execution be done in parallel. We are looking for this support in liquibase as it handles rollback as well. Otherwise, in custom implementation there will be overhead of handling rollback of multiple threads.